# How can I fix this if/let statement within the encode function?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

```
class story: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var label = UILabel()
    var title = String()
    var index = Int()
    var cover = UIImage()
    var frame = CGRect()

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        if let label = label { aCoder.encodeObject(label, forKey: "label") as! UILabel }
        if let title = title { aCoder.encodeObject(title, forKey: "title") }
        if let index = index { aCoder.encodeObject(index, forKey: "index") }
        if let cover = cover { aCoder.encodeObject(cover, forKey: "cover") }
        if let frame = frame { aCoder.encodeObject(frame, forKey: "frame") }
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        self.label = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "label") as! UILabel
        self.title = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as! String
        self.index = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "index") as! Int
        self.cover = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "cover") as! UIImage
        self.frame = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "frane") as! CGRect
    }

    func formatStorySize() {
        let newWidth = self.frame.width * 0.8
        let newHeight = self.frame.height * 0.9
        let newX = self.frame.origin.x + newWidth / 2
        let newY = self.frame.origin.y + newHeight / 2

        self.frame = CGRect(x: newX, y: newY, width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
    }

    func addLabel(text: String) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        label.text = text
        label.textAlignment = .center
        let width = self.frame.width
        let height: CGFloat = 40
        let xPos = self.frame.origin.x
        let yPos = self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.height - height
        label.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: width, height: height)
        self.title = label.text!
        return(label)
    }
}
```

I was told that in order to save an array of custom class instances to `UserDefaults`, I would have to add the encode function as well as the decode function. However, I am getting the error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UILabel'

after the first line within the encode function, and a similar error after all sequential lines. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

None the properties are optional so you don't need `if let` at all in your `encode` method.

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(label, forKey: "label")
    aCoder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
    aCoder.encode(index, forKey: "index")
    aCoder.encode(cover, forKey: "cover")
    aCoder.encode(frame, forKey: "frame")
}
```

Having resolved that, you should not be using `UserDefaults` to save data. Write the encoded data to a file.

Answer (score 0):

When you use conditional binding e.g `if let this = that`, `that` must be an optional.

Use `var label:UILabel?` instead of `var label = UILabel()`